# How to approach Django app in another Docker Container?

Tags: django, docker

I running Django Projects with Docker Container.

Theres' three containers in Server.

1. Accounts Container
2. Blogs Container
3. Etc Container

**Situation.**

I want to approach to Accoutns Container in Blogs Container.

**Why.**

There's Article Table in Blogs Conatiner.

And Blogs Container doesn't have accounts app.

so I have to approach to accounts app in Accounts Container.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ...
```

I dont have any idea :(

Comment: What do you mean by "approach"? You can't reference an app in another container from your models if that's what you are asking. Why do you have to split your project into multiple containers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you for comment!
Oh, "approach" means "reference" right, thanks!


Q. Why do you have to split your project into multiple containers?
A. For MSA(MicroService Architecture).  So split Django Project with 3 Docker Container

Comment: That's not how MSA works. Containers will have to communicate over a REST API or using queues. You are overly complicating things before you are proficient with Django.